# Can't complete displaying alert in react native redux app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer for login to application.
I want to display `Alert` when something goes wrong.
Login action that dispatch show modal action:

```
export function loginUser(username, password) { ...
   dispatch({type: 'SHOW_MODAL', modalType: 'SUCESSFULL_LOGIN'})
```

Modal reducer:

```
export default function reducer(state={}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW_MODAL':
      return {
        modalType: action.modalType
      }
  }
  return state
}
```

But now I don't know where to go next.
Where to read `state` now and display `Alert` view.

Answer (score 2):

You need connect your component to redux and get needed properties from state.
Example:

```
const stateMap = (state, props, ownProps) => {
    return(
       /* Here all your state */
       /* name_property: state.name_action_import.name_property_on_state*/
       modalType: state.login.modalType
    )
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        // This you put action on this component if you need
   };
};
```

*Here you connect your component to redux*

```
export default connect(stateMap, mapDispatchToProps)(Alers);
```

And this variable in component you can get from props like:
    `this.props.modalType`

Your component Alert will look like:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import login from './../../../actions'; /* Here your inport to action */

class Alers extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                {this.props.modalType /*here you property from state */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}


const stateMap = (state, props, ownProps) => {
    return {
        modalType: state.login.modalType
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
    };
};

export default connect(stateMap, mapDispatchToProps)(Alers);
```

Comment: Can you please add a bit more code I still don't understand what should do :/

Comment: And you need dispatch your action